# How to count the number of inputs in Java

Tags: java

I want to enter two integers, `a` and `b`, but if I enter more than two integers or less than two integers, how can I display it on the screen? For example, I'd like to display "too few arguments" when I enter only one integer.

```
public class Box {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();


        if(a>0){
            if(b>0){
            for (int i=0;i<b;i++){

                for (int j=0;j<a;j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
            }
            }else if(b==0){

            }else{
                System.out.println("Negative height");
            }
        }else if(a<0){
            if(b>0){
                System.out.println("Negative width");
            }else if(b==0){

            }else{
                System.out.println("Negative dimensions");
            }

        }else{}         

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you taking the input using a console?

Comment: First of all it does't make any sense : int a = in.nextInt();int b = in.nextInt(); ,after these two lines the user will not be able to enter more integers and if the users enters only one integer[ say a ] then your program as of now will wait until user enters the next integer also.....so the only posibility of your program to run is to get 2 integer inputs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about that. If you enter less than 2 integers the System is going to wait until you input the correct number of integers since `nextInt()` is blocking.

If you want to know if more integers have been entered (this isn't going to be a problem since the Scanner already has what it needs and is going to execute the rest of your program), you could read an String instead of two integers and then, parse the String with another Scanner, if once you have parsed the two integers it has more, you print what you want.

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 String tem = in.next();
 Scanner parser = new Scanner(tem);
 int a = parser.nextInt();
 int b = parser.nextInt();
 if (parser.hasNextInt()){
    // Do whatever print
 }
```

EDIT: 
 Note that with this option, the user must enter the integers within one line and the user can't enter the numbers in different lines as it could be done in your way. You get the advantage of knowing the things you want to, but you need to make further checks in order to ensure the correct execution and no exception is raised.

`> number1 number2 opt`